# Reading a binary file and rewriting

Tags: c, struct, binaryfiles

So i first made a program that created a binary file and that program looks like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct employee {
    char firstname[40];
    char lastname[40];
    int id;
    float GPA;
};
typedef struct employee Employee;

void InputEmpRecord(Employee *);
void PrintEmpList(const Employee *);
void SaveEmpList(const Employee *, const char *);
int main()
{
    Employee EmpList[4];
    InputEmpRecord(EmpList);
    PrintEmpList(EmpList);
    SaveEmpList(EmpList, "employee.dat");
    return 0;
}

 void InputEmpRecord(Employee *EmpList)
{
    int knt;
    for(knt = 0; knt < 4; knt++) {
        printf("Please enter the data for person %d: ", knt + 1);
        scanf("%d %s %s %f", &EmpList[knt].id, EmpList[knt].firstname,EmpList[knt].lastname, &EmpList[knt].GPA);
    }
}

void PrintEmpList(const Employee *EmpList)
{
    int knt;
    for(knt = 0; knt < 4; knt++) {
        printf("%d %s %s %.1f\n", EmpList[knt].id, EmpList[knt].firstname,EmpList[knt].lastname, EmpList[knt].GPA);
    }
}

void SaveEmpList(const Employee *EmpList, const char *FileName)
{
     FILE *p;
    int knt;
    p = fopen(FileName, "wb");
    fwrite(EmpList, sizeof(Employee), 4, p);
    fclose(p);
}
```

Which creates a file and stores 4 employee data structs in it. So i then need to open the file in a separate program and reads the data adn prints it out to stdout in ascii form so i attempted this by:

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct employee {
    char firstname[40];
    char lastname[40];
    int id;
    float GPA;
};

void read(FILE*);
int main()
{
    FILE *p;
    p = fopen("employee.dat", "rb+");
    read(p);
    fclose(p);
    return 0;
}

void read(FILE *p)
{
    struct employee data;
    int knt = 0, a;
    while(!feof(p)) {
        fread(&data.id, sizeof(int), 1, p);
        fread(data.firstname, sizeof(char), 40, p);
        fgets(data.lastname, 40, p);
        fscanf(p, "%f", &data.GPA);
        printf("%s %s %d %f", data.firstname, data.lastname, data.id, data.GPA);
        knt++;
    } 
}
```

The reason i use fread, fgets and fscanf in the while loop is because i wanted to see which one if any would work. I also know that `while(!feof(p))` is bad but my prof said he wants us to use it for the time being and he will teach us how to fix that soon. I get some output but its just seemingly random symbols and numbers.

Comment: `fread(&data, sizeof(data), 1, p);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Okay so that works perfectly thank you but quick question. How does the data go into the specified variable within the struct? Like just by that one fread statement how did data.firstname know to go into that variable because that is somewhat confusing to me

Comment: because you write by `fwrite(EmpList, sizeof(Employee), 4, p);`. `fwrite` => `fread`  Note that you are out to write a memory image of fixed length.

Comment: Note: `feof()` is used incorrectly.  Check the return values from `fread()`, fgets()`, `fscanf()` instead.  Mixing these 3 input functions in the same code  is challenging.  Better to stick with one like `fgets()` is data is textual.

Comment: @chux yeah i know i relized that the hard way (after my program responded poorly) so that has been taken care of

Comment: Consider this approach:  1) Clearly define the file format, 2) define the code structures, then the 3) code to write and read them.  Maybe an employee/line "first name" "last name" 1-12digitID digit.digtGPA ?